# How can I abort a javascript function if a second call to it is made?

Tags: javascript, android

How can I kill a Javascript function if it's still running when it gets called again?

Situation is this. I have an HTML5 Android app which has a search function. As the user types, it searches the HTML5 database for matches. Each keystroke in the search box fires off a function to get suggestions. But because the user can type faster than the database engine can return suggestions on relatively slow devices (like my own, or indeed the emulator) subsequent keypresses get queued up, so that it can take a while for the suggestions to match what the user's typed.

So what I'd like to do is to find some way of killing off a previous invocation of the getSuggestions function if it's invoked again before finishing.

Easy enough to set a global which the function tests at various stages and aborts if it sees it, but that won't stop queries piling up in the database engine, which I'm guessing is probably where the blockage is occurring. Which is why I'm looking for some way to kill off the whole function.

Comment: *"Is there a way to kill a Javascript function if it's still running when it gets called again?"* - JavaScript execution is single-threaded. It is not possible for the function call to occur if the function is still running (unless it calls itself, directly or indirectly). The function must return, and only then it can be called again.

Comment: ...wait until the user pauses typing before sending request: 0.8 seconds works well

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want [underscore.js debounce method](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Basically you would use it like this: (using jQuery for brevity)

```
$('#searchfield').keyup(_.debounce(getSuggestions, 250));
```

This will invoke the `getSuggestions` function only when the event hasn't fired for 250 ms.  So if you are typing, nothing happens until you pause for at least a quarter second.

How it works is pasted below.  It wraps a bunch of logic around a function and returns a new function. Isn't functional programming fun?

```
  // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
  // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
  // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
  // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
  _.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout, result;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
      return result;
    };
  };
```

Comment: I see two problems with this approach: First, what if you do take more than 250ms to find a letter (slow typer) and second, you delay each suggestion by 250ms unnecessarily...

Comment: Then use [`throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) instead. It will fire right away, and continuously as long as they keep typing, but it won't fire too fast flooding your server with search suggestions queries.

Comment: I'm always amazed how quickly good suggestions come back on this site. No wonder I've never been able to answer a question before someone else has. Thanks to all for your ideas. I'm going to be busy tomorrow.

Comment: My pleasure. And underscore.js makes JS better. I highly recommend geting to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is single threaded, it won't be possible to interrupt a function execution. The browser will simply "freeze" until the function returns. In fact, you won't even be able to set a global variable.

So, what you need to do is to break up your search into little pieces (search 1% of the database at a time, for example). Make sure each piece takes no more than 100ms to execute on any device. Then keep calling the search function for the different pieces in the browser's event loop using SetTimeout(getSomeMoreSuggestions, 0) for example.

Then, you can check whether the user made a change to the edit box every time before you reschedule the next execution of the search (i.e. right before SetTimeout).

Comment: I'm fairly sure "still running" in this case doesn't mean running actual code. I think it means "waiting for an XHR response".

Comment: @AlexWayne XHR replies are handled asynchronously... So you can simply ignore the result when it comes in. It shouldn't block any execution, unless, of course, you are hitting the maximum of 2 simultaneously open XHR requests. But even in that case, have each request only search part of the database to make it return quicker. Or, in that special case, you could get really fancy and use the second XHR request to kill the execution of the first one on the server... But I doubt he's got that complicated of a setup that he's talking about.